# Subdirectory import giving error only when module gets imported from package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I've this package called [`classevivaAPI`](https://pypi.org/project/classevivaAPI/0.2.0.dev3/) on `PyPI` (you can find it on `GitHub` [`here`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva)), of which I've for obvious reasons a `git` clone on my computer.

---

```
# main.py
from paths import paths
from variables.variables import *
```

In `main.py` I've the `import`s above, when `main.py` is the file marked as modified (with an `M`) below.

[image: This is the file structure]

---

I'm testing this package with `test.py`, the `gitignore`d file at the bottom of the screenshot, which has the following content:

```
#!\usr\bin\env python3
from classeviva import Session, Valutazioni, Note, Registro
from classeviva.variables import NoteSortBy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Some code here
```

`classeviva` is the module included in the package `classevivaAPI`, and `test.py` is importing it via `pip`, I tested it and it gave me the same problem even if runned from a directory very far from `src/` and in general `src/classeviva`.

When I ran it it gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Python\Classeviva\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from classeviva import Session, Valutazioni, Note, Registro
  File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\classeviva\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .main import *
  File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\classeviva\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from paths import paths
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paths'
```

I was quite confused since I had followed what explained [`here`](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-import-from-subdirectory/), [`here`](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-import-from-subdirectory/) and expecially [`here`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules).

---

So I had the idea to copy paste the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block of `test.py` at the bottom of `main.py`, and surprisingly **it ran perfectly** without giving me any error.

---

Does anybody know what is happening? Have you ever experienced this? Do you know how to fix it or what I'm doing wrong?

## Edit

---

I searched for the module (`classeviva`) into the folder on my hard disk containing all the pip-installed modules, and I found it.

I opened its `main.py`, and the `Visual Studio Code` intellisense told me the same thing as `CPython` did before: there was no subfolder called `path`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`setup.py`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva/blob/v0.2.0-dev.4/setup.py) file was missing the information about the submodules, I added them this way:

```
packages=[
    'classeviva',
    'classeviva.exceptions',
    'classeviva.paths',
    'classeviva.variables'
],
package_dir={
    '': 'src',
    'classeviva.exceptions': 'src/classeviva/exceptions',
    'classeviva.paths': 'src/classeviva/paths',
    'classeviva.variables': 'src/classeviva/variables',
},
```

---

I changed my `main.py` `import`s to the following:

```
# main.py
from .paths import paths
from .variables.variables import *
```

The `.`s were needed to access the subdirectories.

---

Now everything works fine.